# Getting data from connected table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I've two tables like this.

```
create table teams (
  "ID" Integer NOT NULL ,
  "STADIUM_ID" Integer NOT NULL ,
  "NAME" Varchar2 (50) NOT NULL ,
    primary key ("ID") 
    ) ;

create table matches (
  "ID" Integer NOT NULL ,
  "HOMETEAM_ID" Integer NOT NULL ,
  "OPPONENT_ID" Integer NOT NULL ,
  "HOMESCORE" Integer,
  "OPPONENTSCORE" Integer,
primary key ("ID","HOME_ID","OPPONENT_ID") 
) ;
```

They have the following data :

```
select * from matches;

ID      HOME_ID OPPONENT_ID HOMESCORE OPPONENTSCORE
 1          5           2           5             2
 2          4           5           1             0
 3          3           2           1             0
 4          3           2           1             0
 5          1           2           2             0
 6          3           1           2             1

select * from teams;

ID     STADIUM_ID    NAME
 1          1        Team1
 2          3        Team2
 3          4        Team3
 4          2        Team4
 5          5        Team5
```

I need to get the teams that lost the match at home (with the same stadiumid as the winner). Really appriciate your help...
Expected result - none for this data, because every team has their own stadium.

Some query that won't work, but will show what i want to get.

```
select op.name from matches, (select name, stadium_id from teams where id = matches.home_id) home, (select name, stadium_id from teams where id = matches.opponent_id) op where home.stadium_id = op.stadium_id;
```

There are two problems in this query - i'm not comparing the score to get the team that lost, and i cant access matches in subqueries like this.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: On a sidenote: Primary key for `MATCHES` should be `ID` alone. Then there should be an additional unique constraint (unique index) on `(HOMETEAM_ID, OPPONENT_ID)`. And then there should be foreign keys for `HOMETEAM_ID` and `OPPONENT_ID` referencing `TEAMS.ID`. (As to your example: You have made the mistake to call the home team column sometimes `HOME_ID` and sometimes `HOMETEAM_ID`.)

Comment: Sorry all for confusion, i realised that the question wasn't formulated in the right way, selected the most fittable answer that also should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want teams that lost at home. Pseudocode: `select from teams where team in (set of home match losers)`.

```
select *
from teams
where id in
(
  select hometeam_id
  from matches
  where homescore < opponentscore
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:

```
select m.*,h.NAME as Home,o.NAME as Opponent from matches as m
Join teams h on h.STADIUM_ID = m.HOMETEAM_ID
Join teams o on o.STADIUM_ID = m.OPPONENT_ID
where m.HOMESCORE < m.OPPONENTSCORE
```

Comment: thanks, ur answer helped a lot, but instead of h.stadium_id and o.stadium_id should be just h.id and o.id

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query if you want only the list of all the teams that have lost at least one match at home. It handles the fact that two teams could play again in the future.

```
SELECT DISTINCT teams.stadium_id, teams.name
FROM matches
INNER JOIN teams ON (matches.home_id = teams.stadium_id)
WHERE matches.homescore < matches.opponentscore
```